# sqlserver select column name + table name on column for translation purpose in c#

Tags: c#, sql, select, datatable

I need to translate column names from resultsets, my idea is to have a translation table with this format:

```
Culture   Item           Translation
en        'Table1.Name'  'Name'
en        'Table2.Name'  'Name of Table 2'
```

I have a DataTable in c# with a resultset with join of Table1 and Table2 (sqlserver) and I want to translate ColumnName before render on screen with the properly language, the problem is I don't have the table name as part of column name so I cannot search the value on translation table, any idea how to solve this situation?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Do you want fix a query or a column display? And what is the deal with the second translation?

Comment: Normally this would not be done in SQL -- what exactly is "rendering" the result?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have an asp.net mvc app where I render in html some tables from storedprocedures, I want to translate column names to the properly language, but different tables have same column name for different purpose so ...

Comment: Just improve your question, We shouldnt have to guess what are you trying to do. Show us a query, An image of your page. What you have, What you want. When the change lenguaje occurs. Right now only see one lenguaje

Comment: btw, multi-lenguaje application have been done a lot of time, maybe you are trying to invent the wheel instead of looking for a proved solution. Usually using resource files. http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: you don't want to do this in sql -- asp mvc has lots of features to enable localization -- use those.

Comment: @Hogan but all those features are for access to the database through Models and I'm using .net datatable I searched for some examples but I couldn't find its. thx anyway

Comment: I have no idea what you mean @JuanCarlosOropeza 's link above should work find and the example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.140%29.aspx (a link in that article) has **nothing** to do with MVC or Models.  Did you actually spend the time to read more than two words on this link?

Comment: @hogan what is wrong with my link?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - the "I have no idea what you mean" was directed at Santiago not at you.  Read my whole comment :)